# HTTP Status Codes Json

Tags: java, json, rest, api

Until now I have been doing my API's something like this:

```
    @GET
    @GZIP
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response login(@QueryParam("email") String email, @QueryParam("password") String password){  
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        String token = userDao.getLogin(email, password);
        if(token != null)
            return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();

        return Response.status(400).build();
    }
```

And it works perfectly fine because in the client I just call the http service and it returns the token a string response or a json response.

But I did some research on other API's and I saw that their format is a little more complex than just a string/json response.

So I am trying to build some more serious structure I created an object for the response like this:

```
public class JsonResponse {

    private String success;
    private String error;
    private Object data;

    public JsonResponse(){

    }

    public JsonResponse(String success, String error, Object data) {
        this.success = success;
        this.error = error;
        this.data = data;
    }

    //GETTERS/SETTERS...
}
```

So I changed the REST part from that one above to this:

```
    @GET
    @GZIP
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(@QueryParam("email") String email, @QueryParam("password") String password){
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        JsonResponse jsonResponse = userDao.login(email, password);
        if(jsonResponse.getSuccess() != null)
            return Response.status(200).entity(jsonResponse).build();

        return Response.status(400).entity(jsonResponse).build();
    }
```

This way what I can do in the client is obtain the response instead of just the token string I get it like this:

```
{
success: "success",
error: null,
data: "$2a$10$nT0vSwBCDiRl1Xvfrqrh1un8Iu/w3OInjp.JQDKux1aA6YZoyfEt2"
}
```

or

```
{
success: null,
error: "An error occured because of '...specific problem from api...'",
data: "$2a$10$nT0vSwBCDiRl1Xvfrqrh1un8Iu/w3OInjp.JQDKux1aA6YZoyfEt2"
}
```

**So my problem is the following:**
When the api send STATUS_CODE 200 I can indeed use that JSON

But when it returns STATUS_CODE 400 I can't get the error message from the json because the json is not sent

Do I need to use always STATUS_CODE 200 if I want to do the API like that?
What are the best practice?

Comment: no using status code 200 for error is not good practice.what is the erro you are getting? and can you add the code where you are trying to get the resposne

Comment: The error is that the password is incorrect. I am just using postman to see the response.

Comment: i meant what is the response you are getting in postman? and you are sending null object inresponse with status 400 so obviously you wont get anything in response body

Comment: _"But when it returns STATUS_CODE 400 I can't get the error message from the json because the json is not sent"_ - Why not? Why is there no body? Aren't you setting it? Do you mean when there is an error and your resource method doesn't even get hit and Jersey automatically sends out the response?

Comment: Yes @Paul Samsotha that was the error I was not setting the body. Already solved the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you are not getting accurate error responses because the request could have invalid syntax. Since 400 is bad request, it could be syntax, credentials, or even connection to the api itself. The reason you are not receiving an error message makes it seem like the api is not able to send one back to your machine. Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Hey Jack, thank you for answering! So should I return 200 and send the error message? In this case It only gives 400 if I fail the password because I made it like that.

Comment: Hey Daniflipers, I would follow practices brought about by the standardized Http status codes. For example, if the api does not authenticate you correctly, returning a Forbidden 403 or 401 Unauthorized. There is a good list I have found over the years: https://httpstatusdogs.com/ Its always good to give the user a little more info, even if its just through a status code! Hope that helps a little more!

Comment: One more note, Its also good to use the standardized codes through http status codes, because they often denote where the error has occurred(Ex: http 500 errors mean there is a problem with the server)

Comment: Thank you I will check that up. I already solved my problem, it was my bad I was just returning the 400 code with no entity attached in a condition that I was not seeing.